# PHP Script Memory Leaking Until Eventual Overflow

Tags: php, memory

Keep running into a weird problem with a PHP script.  The idea of the script is to grab a bunch of data from a MySQL table, process it, compare it some data from another table, and print out the results to a file in CSV format.

This script will run several hundreds of thousands of iterations to complete.  Problem I have is that even with using unset() on the arrays and free() on my MySQL queries, memory continues to be used up until around iteration 350,000 or so it runs out of memory.

Without fail, every time I run the script the memory allocation as reported by memory_get_usage() stays the same until approximately ever 1050 iterations.  Then it will increase by exactly 262,144 bytes.  Through testing it also always increments in the exact same place in the script.  In the code block below it will always increment in one of the iterations of b2a (maximum of 4 possible iterations).

```
//up here we get the data to run analysis/comparisons on.

echo "{$lineCounter}b:  " . memory_get_usage(TRUE) . "\n"; //27525120
if ($AttResults = $db_cx->query($ObsAttQuery)) {
   echo "{$lineCounter}b1:  " . memory_get_usage(TRUE) . "\n"; //27525120
   $attArray = array();
   echo "{$lineCounter}b2: " . memory_get_usage(TRUE) . "\n"; //27525120
   while ($attRow = $AttResults->fetch_object()) {
      echo "{$lineCounter}b2a {$attRow->attId}: " . memory_get_usage(TRUE) . "\n"; //27787264
      $attArray[$attRow->attId] = $attRow->value;
   }
echo "{$lineCounter}b3: " . memory_get_usage(TRUE) . "\n"; //27787264
$AttResults->free();
if (empty($attArray)) continue;

//down here after it is done I have an unset on the $attArray variable
```

Any suggestions on things to try??

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? PHP 5.3 improved memory usage significantly over 5.2.

Comment: I am using 5.4.11 and the script is being called from the command line (if that makes any difference).

Comment: I don't quite understand where the hundreds of thousand iterations come from. Does the shown while-loop run that often? Or is the whole script inside a loop?

Comment: @fab: The whole script runs inside a loop; otherwise his comments (in the code) would not make sense.

Comment: It is within two while loops.  The outermost is a do...while loop that breaks up the incoming data into large chunks and the innermost loops over each row from the query.  I had to break up the outermost chunk or the larger queries would kill the memory right away.  I am trying to get this to run over a data set of around 53 million entries.  But for now I would be happy if it could complete 1 million.

Comment: I just was wondering, how to interpret `//27787264` inside the loop. Does this loop run only once?

Comment: @fab - sorry, probably should have explained those.  The numbers I showed as comments are actual examples of how and where the memory usage report would change.  That would be from just one of the iterations.  I do find it intriguing that they change reliably approximately every 1050 iterations (from one test run the intervals were 1056, 1053, 1045, 1054...) and that the change was always exactly 262,144 bytes.

Comment: Are you using any global or static variables in your script?  Also you may want to try to unset the array entries individually.

Comment: hmm, i dont want to be a nitpicker. if contains an assignment operator. i would drop the while loop, in favor of a foreach. after the call to $attResukts->free(), you might add an gc_collect_cycles(), testwise.

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch - Removed the assignment from the if, switched to a foreach loop using a fetch_all, and added the free() and the gc_collect_cycles().  No change in memory usage.


Additionally, I was thinking that since I was writing out to a file, maybe the file handle was increasing in size so I tried closing/reopening every 100k lines or so.  Actually increased the memory usage so went back to single open at beginning and close at the end.

Comment: @RightHandedMonkey - No globals or statics.  Tried that unset of entries individually.  No change in memory usage.

Comment: @Brian Try to address your database call.  Make sure your SELECT query only grabs the two pieces information you need (that will make the db do less work).  In the case above it looks like just two items.  Additionally, try fetching as an array not an object.  Objects take longer to create and use more memory (just like the foreach would).  Do: $attRow = $AttResults->fetch_array().  And then access the column entries with $attRow[0] and $attRow[1].

Answer (score 0):

Prior to version 5.3 php had a very stupid garbage collector: [Memory Leaks With Objects in PHP 5](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/262). With this you could not even free your memory with `unset()`. You have to break circular references before you unset, or simply use at least php 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the data retrieved by:

```
$attRow = $AttResults->fetch_object()
```

before/around iteration 1050 ?

...and... yes, I would change the assignment in the while with one fetch before the loop and one before the end to see if the memory changes.

Comment: I have inspected it.  The variable contains an associative array with 3-6 elements in it.  Switched to a fetch_all() and the memory usage has not changed.